# Remove elements from list that fulfill condition

Tags: c++, list, function, syntax-error, runtime-error

I have a list containing 'Window' objects, every Window has a title, a handle and a state. I'm trying to remove every Window from the list that fulfills the condition (getTitle() == "") but can't figure out a way to do it..

I've tried a for loop using the list iterator but it gave me a runtime error saying "list iterator not incrementable" most likely because you're not supposed to change elements if you use the iterator

I've also tried the remove_if() operation of lists but I can't figure out how to use it with my condition since I'm not trying to remove elements with a certain value, but elements whose function returns a certain value.

Hope someone can help

Comment: `myList.remove_if( [](const Window& w) { return w.getTitle() == ""; } );`

Comment: Thank you so much, worked perfectly!

Comment: FWIW, [a reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove) for the function that includes such an example.